# ngFor iterate n+1 times to have at least 1 value

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a form where you can add fields on, and I want to make sure that at least one form is available.

Code example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-riffgs?file=app/app.component.html

I need the form to enter the phone numbers render at least one. Is there a way to iterate n + 1 times for ngFor, or any other way to make sure ngFor renders at least once?

Comment: You can simply add another form separate from the ngfor block  to enter the details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one empty **phoneNumber** object if the phoneNumbers array is empty, so when you initialize the form you should check if phoneNumbers has items.

```
ngOnInit(){
  if(!person.phoneNumbers.length){
    let emptyPhoneNumber = {
       type: '',
       phoneNumber: ''
    };

    this.person.phoneNumbers.push(emptyPhoneNumber);
 }
}
```

Please note that this isn't the right way to configure forms, check the docs for more info. But I add a solution based on your example, and you can apply the same empty object on **formControl**.